# Why would Strapi admin fail to login when site domain go through CloudFront CDN?

Tags: nginx, amazon-cloudfront, strapi

When we point our domain to CloudFront that proxies requests to our server, we cannot log in to admin anymore, when we type email and password, then click the submit button, it first seems like log-in was successful, then it redirects back to the login page. The only error shown in the console is 401 for the following pages:

```
/information
/permissions
/me
```

When we make the domain point directly to our server, we then can log in with no issues.
In all cases, we use Nginx which passes requests to the actual Strapi server through `proxy_pass`.

Are there any settings we need to tweak on Strapi? Or are there any headers/settings that need to be added to the CDN service?

Strapi is almost vanilla, other than the URL, models, and db settings, there aren't any actual customizations.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where you able to solve this ?

Comment: @user1237981 IIRC, we had to redirect all headers from CloudFront, can't remember clearly, sorry.